What ROS2 Topic can I use to detect when a robot does a left or right turn?
I'm working with a tank-style, differential-wheeled robot and facing a challenge in achieving precise directional control. Specifically, when the robot attempts to turn left or right, it tends to overshoot, veering off the intended straight path after rotating on its z-axis. Despite RVIZ showing a direct trajectory to waypoints, the robot strays, swerving left or right instead of maintaining a straight line. My goal is to mitigate this overshoot, enhancing the robot's ability to navigate in a more aligned manner.

Along with checking the RVIZ, you should also check the speed given by the move_base / nav2. In a straight path, the /cmd_vel should only give a positive value for the linear x-axis and 0 for the angular z-axis.
If this is indeed the case, you should check the motor driver program, which translates the /cmd_vel to the speed for each wheel. The absolute value for each wheel should be the same for straight-path planning. If the robot turns left, the speed of the right wheel is higher than the left wheel, and vice versa.
If all of the above cases behave correctly, I think you should check the design of the wheel, one of the wheels might not parallel to the other.

Without other informations on which kimd of sensors yuo have available is a bit difficoult to help.
What i would check is if the parameters of the physical robot are the same of the ones you have in simulation.
Could also be the motor drivers that are not setup correctly/adequate to the task.

This should have probably been a comment, rather than an answer.
